# Multiple Items in django-paypal

Tags: django, django-paypal

I am using dcramer's version of django-paypal(but i think it shouldnt matter whether it is dcramer or johnboxall's).

1) How can i specify multiple items in my paypal_dict(to be used in PayPalPaymentsForm)?
2) Also, i need to suitably specify the shipping cost and the individual quantities in the Summary that appears in the Paypal screen - how do i do this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not fond of django-paypal. Just read the PayPal api:  https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=p/pdn/howto_checkout-outside.

To push all the items in your cart to PayPal:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
        <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="you@youremail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="EUR">

        <!-- Run a for loop -->
        {% for item in cart %}
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name 1">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="10.00">
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item Name 2">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="20.00">
        .
        .
        .
        <input type="hidden" name="item_name_N" value="Item Name N">
        <input type="hidden" name="amount_N" value="30.00">
        {% endfor %}

        <input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! , after your answer my approach is now: i'll do the cart form generation and let django-paypal do the IPN handling.

Answer (score 0):

I end up building item dictionaries like this in the view:

```
item = {
    'cancelurl':     'http://%s%s' % DYNAMIC_URL, reverse('pay_cancel')), # Express checkout cancel url
    'returnurl':     'http://%s%s' % (DYNAMIC_URL, reverse('pay_now')), # Express checkout return url

    'l_name0':       'Your product name',
    'l_number0':     1234,
    'l_desc0':       'longer description',
    'l_amt0':        100.00,
    'l_qty0':        1,

    'l_name1':       'Your product name',
    'l_number1':     1234,
    'l_desc1':       'longer description',
    'l_amt1':        200.00
    'l_qty1':        2,

    'itemamt':       500.00,
    'taxamt':        0.00,
    'shippingamt':   0.00,
    'handlingamt':   0.00,
    'shipdiscamt':   0.00,
    'insuranceamt':  0.00,
    'amt':           500.00, # Amount to charge for basket
}
```

This dict then gets bundled up like this:

```
kw = {
    'item': item,
    'payment_template': 'cms/register.html', # Template name for payment
    'confirm_template': 'cms/paypal-confirmation.html', # Template name for confirmation
    'success_url':      reverse('pay_success'), # Ultimate return URL
}

ppp = PayPalPro(**kw)
return ppp(request)
```

Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to to make paypal work with your cart.
Use a for loop for items in the cart.
In order to get a number for each item for paypal to recognize them i use
item.id

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block content %}

<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
<input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
<input type="hidden" name="business" value="account@mail.com">
<input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
{% for item in cart %}

<input type="hidden" name="item_name_{{item.id}}" value="  
{{item.name}}">
<input type="hidden" name="amount_{{item.id}}" value="{{item.price}}">
{% endfor %}

<input type="image" src="http://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" 
name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
</form>


{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Usually it's better to explain a solution instead of just posting some rows of anonymous code. You can read [How do I write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), and also [Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bcode-based-answers)