# Paypal "_cart" implementation with django-paypal

Tags: paypal, django-forms, django-paypal

I am working with django-paypal ipn.standard and am trying to get it working with a paypal's "_cart" option. However, I cannot make it work.

I use this dictionary to initialize the forms:

```
cart {
  'amount_1': '0.99',
  'amount_2': '0.99',
  'business': 'seller_436_biz@foo.com',
  'cancel_return': 'http://www.foo.com/ccled/',
  'cmd': '_cart',
  'invoice': '1',
  'item_name_1': 'Item 1',
  'item_name_2': 'Item 2',
  'notify_url': 'http://www.foo.com/ntfy/',
  'return_url': 'http://www.doo.com/done/'
}

form = PayPalPaymentForm(initial=cart)
```

I have also tried adding "CMD_CHOICES":"_cart" to the above dict, but didn't make a difference

However, on using {{ form.render }} I get the Buy-Now button with the html below:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="seller_436_biz@foo.com" id="id_business" />
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="'http://www.foo.com/ntfy//" id="id_notify_url" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="http://www.foo.com/ccled/" id="id_cancel_return" />
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.foo.com/done/" id="id_return_url" />
  <input type="hidden" name="invoice" value="1" id="id_invoice" />
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart" id="id_cmd" />
  <input type="hidden" name="charset" value="utf-8" id="id_charset" />
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD" id="id_currency_code" />
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1" id="id_no_shipping" />
  <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="Buy it Now" />
</form>
```

None of the shopping cart items are shown.

I was looking at a couple of other threads like [Multiple Items in django-paypal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011655/multiple-items-in-django-paypal). To try it out, I cut-pasted the 'item' dictionary from that example, and passed it to my PayPalPaymentForm. However, again, in the form, I do not see the items being sold.

What am I missing, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured what I was missing. The form should be created with "cart" option:

```
form = PayPalPaymentForm(initial=cart, button_type="cart")
```

Comment: When i add "button_type = 'cart'" I get a KeyError saying (True , 'cart'). Did you do some additional stuff or just added the button type and the cmd value ?

Comment: @SuburbanFilth that error seems to be around just generating the image for the button. I couldn't get this to work with the current version in pypi. You can download the latest version on github with something like "pip install git+https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/#egg=django-paypal --upgrade". Or if you prefer, you can apply this patch manually: https://github.com/spookylukey/django-paypal/commit/b22611b9d84030c73e11a4571012174846b05812
Then, you don't need to set the button_type.

Answer (score 0):

If ever someone struggles again with this, here is how I managed to fix this for my project. I spent way too much time on this as it was not really well documented and I couldn't find a working example:

```
paypal_dict = {
    'upload': 1, 
    'business': 'account@business.example.com', 
    'invoice': 'INVOICE1', 
    'currency_code': 'CAD', 
    'cmd': '_cart', 
    'charset': 'utf-8', 
    'notify_url': 'http://website.ca/paypal/', 
    'return_url': 'http://website.ca/payment-completed', 
    'cancel_return': 'http://website.ca/payment-failed', 
    'quantity_1': 1, 
    'item_name_1': 'item 1', 
    'item_number_1': 1, #This is just a product ID for your reference
    'shipping_1': 0, 
    'amount_1': 150, 
    'quantity_2': 1, 
    'item_name_2': 'item2', 
    'item_number_2': 2, 
    'shipping_2': 0, 
    'amount_2': 125,
}
paypal_payment_button = PayPalPaymentsForm(initial=paypal_dict, button_type="buy")
```

So what I do is basically just specifying all requirements for each individual products to the PaymentsForm and I also make sure to specify the cmd as _cart. I also provide the upload flag to the cart got uploaded to paypal.

With this I can have all my item with product ID and description directly on the paypal invoice.